# Replacing value depending on paired column

Tags: r, tidyverse, pairwise

I have a dataframe with two columns per sample (n > 1000 samples):

```
df <- data.frame(
    "sample1.a" = 1:5, "sample1.b" = 2,
    "sample2.a" = 2:6, "sample2.b" = c(1, 3, 3, 3, 3),
    "sample3.a" = 3:7, "sample3.b" = 2)
```

If there is a zero in column .b, the correspsonding value in column .a should be set to NA.

I thought to write a function over colnames (without suffix) to filter each pair of columns and conditional exchaning values. Is there a simpler approach based on tidyverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the data.frame into a list of data.frames and do the replacement in `base R`

```
df1 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(split.default(df,  
   sub("\\..*", "", names(df))), function(x) {
             x[,1][x[2] == 0] <- NA
      x}))
```

---

Or another option is `Map`

```
acols <- endsWith(names(df), "a")
bcols <- endsWith(names(df), "b")
df[acols] <- Map(function(x, y) replace(x, y == 0, NA), df[acols], df[bcols])
```

---

Or if the columns are alternate with 'a', 'b' columns, use a logical index for recycling, create the logical matrix with 'b' columns and assign the corresponding values in 'a' columns to NA

```
df[c(TRUE, FALSE)][df[c(FALSE, TRUE)] == 0] <- NA
```

---

or an option with `tidyverse` by reshaping into 'long' format (`pivot_longer`), changing the 'a' column to `NA` if there is a correspoinding 0 in 'a', and reshape back to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_sep="\\.",
        names_to = c('group', '.value')) %>% 
   mutate(a = na_if(b, a == 0)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = c(a, b)) %>% 
   select(-rn)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#  a_sample1 a_sample2 a_sample3 b_sample1 b_sample2 b_sample3
#      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1         2         1         2         2         1         2
#2         2         3         2         2         3         2
#3         2         3         2         2         3         2
#4         2         3         2         2         3         2
#5         2         3         2         2         3         2
```

Comment: I think in your tidyverse version `mutate(a = na_if(b, b < 2)` should be correct.